# Ruby on Rails 4, Dynamically create table for each user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dynamic

I'm new to Rails and I'm creating an Application where users can log in, and it dynamically generates a Table where they can make entries. I've managed to make the login but I don't realize how to create a table which is associated to a user.

My users_controller.rb class:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_user, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /users
  # GET /users.json
  def index
    @users = User.order(:name)
  end

  # GET /users/1
  # GET /users/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /users/new
  def new
    @user = User.new 
  end

  # GET /users/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /users
  # POST /users.json
  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
        format.html { redirect_to login_url, notice: "User #{@user.name} was successfully created." }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @user }

#HERE I WOULD LIKE TO CREATE A TABLE ASSOSSIATED TO THE USER
        @rapport_table = User.rapport_table.create

      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /users/1
  # PATCH/PUT /users/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.update(user_params)
        format.html { redirect_to users_url, notice: "User #{@user.name} was successfully updated." }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /users/1
  # DELETE /users/1.json
  def destroy
    @user.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to users_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, :password, :password_confirmation)
    end
end
```

rapport_table.rb

```
class RapportTable < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
end
```

12341324123_create_rapport_tables.rb

```
class CreateRapportTables < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :rapport_tables do |t|
      t.date :date
      t.text :description
      t.integer :time

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
  def self.down
    drop_table :rapport_tables
  end
end
```

show.html.erb

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<p>
  <strong>Name:</strong>
  <%= @user.name %>
</p>



<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_user_path(@user) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', users_path %>
```

Comment: I hope you don't want to actually create a db table for every new user. That's just... wrong.

Comment: how else should I do it?

Answer (score 1):

You never, ever want to create tables inside a database in a runtime. Instead, you'll need to create some more models:

```
class RaportTable < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :columns
  has_many :rows
end

class Column < ActiveRecord::Base
  # attr_accessible :name, :order
  belongs_to :raport_table
  has_many :cells
end

class Row < ActiveRecord::Base
  # attr_accessible :row_number
  belongs_to :raport_table
  has_many :cells
end

class Cell < ActiveRecord::Base
  # attr_accessible :value
  belongs_to :column
  belongs_to :row
end
```

This should be sufficient to start with.